# Passing shared_ptr via variable argument list

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, variadic-functions

Is this possible to do and how would I pass the shared_ptr(s)? I found some related question ([C++ variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807009/c-variable-number-of-arguments/5807530#5807530)) but it does not fully address my question. 
I have tried a few ways to write such function but all I get is an error `error: cannot receive objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘class std::shared_ptr<Item>’ through ‘...’;`

If this is not a good idea at all, how could I pass an arbitrary number of shared_ptr's as an an argument, almost something like variadic templates or such? Maybe this is even more simple than I think ...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not variadic templates?

Comment: I agree with @DavidBrown. [Why not using variadic templates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15465877/1932150)?

Comment: @DavidBrown: I have never used variadic templates, so I am not sure if it would work (actually I have not tried it yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++11 you can either use variadic templates or initializer lists. Initializer lists are a bit easier to use, because they do not require recursion and they can be defined in separate compilation units:

```
void foobar(std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<widget>> widgets);

std::shared_ptr<widget> foo;
std::shared_ptr<widget> bar;
foobar({ foo, bar });
```

Comment: The initializer_list seems also to be an nice option! I will try that too.

Comment: I finally tried this out (also with variadic template) and it seems to work. Thanks for the hint. I just need to get more into the C++11 Details and options ...